# Error while trying to add Liquidity in uniswap pair

Tags: token, blockchain, solidity, hardhat, uniswap

I'm using Hardhat framewrok and doing some testing with an erc20 contract:
I used that tutorial to fork https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/guides/forking-other-networks.
I'm trying to swap two ERC20 tokens in mainnet fork using uniswap
I have created uniswap pair for tokens and I'm trying to add Liquidity.
Here is my code for tests.
I'm sure that I made right contracts for tokens

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers")
const { expect } = require("chai")
const { ethers } = require("hardhat")

//https://unpkg.com/@uniswap/v2-core@1.0.0/build/IUniswapV2Pair.json
const uniswapPairAbi = require("../contracts/IUniswapV2Pair.json")

const uniswapFactoryAbi = require("../contracts/UniswapFactoryAbi.json")

const uniswapRouter02Abi = require("../contracts/IUniswapV2Router02.json")

const daiAbi = require("../contracts/DaiAbi.json")


const uniswapFactoryAddress = "0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f"
const uniswapRouterAddress = "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D "
describe("Swap", function () {
   let owner
 it("Create Token, Create Pair, Swap", async function () {
       [owner, to] = await ethers.getSigners()

       const MyToken = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyToken", owner)
       const myToken = await MyToken.deploy()
       await myToken.deployed()

       const YourToken = await ethers.getContractFactory("YourToken", owner)
       const yourToken = await YourToken.deploy()
       await yourToken.deployed()

       const factory = await ethers.getContractAt(uniswapFactoryAbi, uniswapFactoryAddress)

       console.log("to ", to.address)
       const pair = await factory.createPair(myToken.address, yourToken.address)


       await expect(pair)
               .to.emit(factory, "PairCreated")
       const swapPairMTYTAddress = await factory.getPair(myToken.address, yourToken.address)

       const wapPairMTYTContract = await ethers.getContractAt(uniswapPairAbi, swapPairMTYTAddress)
       const router02Contract = await ethers.getContractAt(uniswapRouter02Abi, uniswapRouterAddress)
       
       await router02Contract.addLiquidity(myToken.address, yourToken.address,1,1,1,1, owner.address, 12)
      
 });
});
```

When I run npx hardhat test. I'm getting such error.

```
npx hardhat test


  Swap
to  0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8
    1) Create Token, Create Pair, Swap


  0 passing (6s)
  1 failing

  1) Swap
       Create Token, Create Pair, Swap:
     Error: network does not support ENS (operation="getResolver", network="unknown", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=providers/5.7.2)
      at Logger.makeError (node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
      at Logger.throwError (node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
      at EthersProviderWrapper.<anonymous> (node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\base-provider.ts:1989:20)
      at step (node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\base-provider.js:48:23)
      at Object.next (node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\base-provider.js:29:53)
      at fulfilled (node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\base-provider.js:20:58)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
```

I'm sure that everything before addLiquidity works correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

const uniswapRouterAddress = "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D "
whitespace shold not be at the end

Answer (score 0):

in:

```
const uniswapRouterAddress = "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D "
```

you can't have spaces or unidentified symbols in an address.
also, try to not hardcode your address as much as you can.